# JMeter View results tree listener displaying duplicate https requests

Tags: performance, jmeter, listener, performance-testing, viewresult

View result listener displaying duplicate https requests, 1 request is without response and 1 request is with having response. I need only 1 request, How can i fix it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxPS9.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5AOt.png)

Comment: Could you give a bit more context ? And also add some tags so that your questions pops up in the right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample with response message as "*Number of samples in transaction : 1, number of failing samples : 0*"  is for the "Transaction Controller" while the other is the actual request with response.

Select the "Generate parent sample" checkbox in the Transaction controller and you will be able to see the desired results.

Transaction Controller will always club the response times for the underlying Http requests. If you don't want to see this in results use "Simple Controller" instead.

Answer (score 0):

Look into "Sampler Result" tab of the View Results Tree listener:

[image]

If you see one of [HTTP status codes 3xx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection) it means that you're being [redirected](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) so it's absolutely normal to see blank response if this is the case of redirection

[image]

You can control the behaviour of the JMeter when it comes to handling redirect responses by playing with `Redirect automatically` and `Follow Redirects` checkboxes in the HTTP Request sampler:

[image]

However you need to remember that you don't "need only 1 request", you need exactly the same number of requests like [real browser sends](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) so inspect how many requests are being sent by the real browser using your favourite [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and ensure that JMeter sends the same amount of requests and they have the same nature

Comment: Thank you for you comprehensive observation and detailed answer, but my issue is still present let me elaborate it more. Like whenever I applied 500 users on it, I found 1000 frames in my report, but actually I targeted 500 frames. 1000 is displaying due to duplication. you can check the response of both requests in attached screenshots

Comment: I have added screenshots with Question's description